# How can values in a Spark array column be efficiently replaced with values from a Pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Spark data frame that contains a column of arrays with product ids from sold baskets.

```python
import pandas as pd 
import pyspark.sql.types as T
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df_baskets = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, ["546", "689", "946"]), (2, ["546", "799"] )],
    ("case_id","basket")
)

df_baskets.show()

#+-------+---------------+
#|case_id|         basket|
#+-------+---------------+
#|      1|[546, 689, 946]|
#|      2|     [546, 799]|
#+-------+---------------+
```

I would like to replace the product ids in each array with new ids given in a pandas data frame.

```python
product_data = pd.DataFrame({
  "product_id": ["546", "689", "946", "799"],
  "new_product_id": ["S12", "S74", "S34", "S56"]
  })

product_data
```

I was able to replace the values by applying a simple python function to the column that performs a lookup on the python data frame.

```python
def get_new_id(product_id: str) -> str:
  try:
    row = product_data[product_data["product_id"] == product_id]
    return row["new_product_id"].item()
  except ValueError:
    return product_id

apply_get = F.udf(lambda basket: [get_new_id(product) for product in basket], T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))

df_baskets = (
  df_baskets
    .withColumn('basket_renamed', apply_get(F.col('basket')))
)

df_baskets.show()

#+-------+---------------+---------------+
#|case_id|         basket| basket_renamed|
#+-------+---------------+---------------+
#|      1|[546, 689, 946]|[S12, S74, S34]|
#|      2|     [546, 799]|     [S12, S56]|
#+-------+---------------+---------------+
```

However, this approach has proven to be quite slow in data frames containing several tens of millions of cases. Is there more efficient way to do this replacement (e.g. by using a different data structure than a pandas data frame or a different method)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could explode your original data and join on `product_data` (after converting it to a spark frame)

```
(
    df_baskets
    .withColumn("basket", F.explode(F.col("basket")))
    .join(
        spark.createDataFrame(product_data)
        .withColumnRenamed("product_id", "basket")
        .withColumnRenamed("new_product_id", "basket_renamed"),
        on="basket"
    )
    .groupby("case_id")
    .agg(
        F.collect_list(F.col("basket")).alias("basket"),
        F.collect_list(F.col("basket_renamed")).alias("basket_renamed")
    )
).show()
```

Output:

```
|case_id|         basket| basket_renamed|
+-------+---------------+---------------+
|      1|[546, 689, 946]|[S12, S74, S34]|
|      2|     [546, 799]|     [S12, S56]|
+-------+---------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use RDD and `map`.

convert the pandas dataframe rows to a `dict` of `{old: new}` values. then use a `map` in RDD to fetch the mapped `new_product_id`.

here's an example

```py
# convert pandas df to dict
# can be done in other ways as well
old_new_id_dict = {}

for i in range(len(product_data_df)):
    old_new_id_dict[product_data_df.loc[i, 'product_id']] = product_data_df.loc[i, 'new_product_id']

# {'546': 'S12', '689': 'S74', '946': 'S34', '799': 'S56'}

old_new_id_dict_bc = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(old_new_id_dict)

# `map` the values
data_sdf.rdd. \
    map(lambda r: (r.case_id, r.basket, [old_new_id_dict_bc.value[k] for k in r.basket])). \
    toDF(['case_id', 'basket', 'new_basket']). \
    show()

# +-------+---------------+---------------+
# |case_id|         basket|     new_basket|
# +-------+---------------+---------------+
# |      1|[546, 689, 946]|[S12, S74, S34]|
# |      2|     [546, 799]|     [S12, S56]|
# +-------+---------------+---------------+
```